# At what point does "Search and Research" become too much to ask?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

[The guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specify that we should "Search and Research" before asking a question. I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981343/why-isnt-my-opengl-ssb-receiving-data-sent-from-the-host) which someone downvoted and voted to close. Their reason to close was "A community-specific reason," and they left no further explanation. I assume they were referencing the "Search and Research" section of the guidelines, as I had a slightly snarky comment in my example code (which [I've edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75981343/2)) which essentially says that I feel like it's more research than I have time for.

So, at what point is asking someone to "search and research" too much?

A couple of quick contrived examples:

- Obviously we wouldn't expect someone new to programming to spend months learning the basics of programming, learning what the stack is, learning about heap memory, etc., just for them to realize that calling a recursive function in an infinite loop will cause a stack overflow.
- Contrarily, we would probably expect someone learning the [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started) to read the documentation to see that, to [create a new emoji](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/emoji#create-guild-emoji), one must [upload the image binary](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-data) in data URI format in a string in a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object. And even that might be a bit too harsh to expect of them.

In any case, I'm just curious where that line is drawn.

Comment: There's only two items under "A community-specific reason" that could potentially apply to your question: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" and "Needs debugging details". I did not verify to see if these do apply, however, none of the others do.

Comment: If you click on close, then on Community, you'll see that the voter chose Needs Debug Detail.  (FWIW you don't have to complete your close vote)

Comment: Re _Obviously we wouldn't expect someone new to programming to spend months learning the basics of programming_ well, actually,  I do.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Not available to those of us without close vote privileges (not enough reputation).

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship true, but [OP gets a lower reputation threshold to see close votes on their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: @chrisneilsen word choice :) we *require* research but *expect that none is provided*...

Comment: Side note: MRE for OpenGL may be better in C/C++ despite your language of choice if you care to get answers...

Comment: "Rough mockup" <> MRE

Comment: @philipxy, yes. Forgive my assumptions, I guess it's pride getting in the way. It's frustrating spending hours looking for an answer, becoming even more confused, then spending nearly an hour on a rough mockup which excludes boilerplate which I assume (again, my bad) anyone familiar enough with the problem to solve it, would also be familiar with boilerplate.
But I misunderstood the site. I've usually gotten answers to my questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109942/what-is-a-stack-map-frame), even if documentation existed. But I understand my mistake.

Comment: FWIW, the closing banner clearly shows the "Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers." and "Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question." (with links) for people being able to close vote. If you as OP of the question really *only* see "A community-specific reason," and "no further explanation" then please clearly state so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, this post was made before the close vote was finalized. There was only 1 vote to close at the time I posted this question. On the original question, I clicked "Close" to see if it would give me any information about the reason for the vote. It turns out it did give me some information, but I didn't pursue it further, as I was worried about accidentally voting to close my question, and I wasn't very familiar with the close menu.

Comment: I think research is a red herring here. Not all questions belong on Stack Overflow. Even questions which are on-topic according to the rules. When it comes to questions about game programming, you are probably better off asking them in a dedicated non-SE site unless it is something VERY specific like a question about the functioning of an API call. In my experience game development problems (or anything related to the tech) can easily result in multiple pages of forum post trying to unroot the source problem AND a viable solution. Stack Overflow just doesn't support that.

Answer (score 18):

Regarding

> Obviously we wouldn't expect someone new to programming to spend months learning .... just for them to realize that calling a recursive function in an infinite loop will cause a stack overflow.

The status of the questioner should have *nothing* to do with how members should respond to questions (including voting and closing) since the key is and always has been the question quality and relevance itself, regardless of who asked it or where they currently are in their programming journey. This isn't a forum or even a help site but rather a question and answer site where the goal is to have a repository of questions and answers that help future visitors. So you ask "where that line is drawn", and my answer is: "there is no line". A question stands and falls on its own.

Having said this, I will add that direct help often is obtained but more of as a beneficial side-effect of the site.

I will also add a useful point brought up by "Andreas detests censorship", in that is usually not fruitful to make assumptions as to why someone voted the way that they did, unless they tell you specifically, and then you're not assuming.

Comment: While correct, I believe Steven came to the wrong conclusion for why the question was downvoted and voted on for closure.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship: You're probably right since none of us can read the minds of other site members. To assume motivation is to run into trouble.

Comment: You can skip the trailing message in my profile name. ;) "[This weirdo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7395227/andreas-detests-censorship)" does the trick.